# Information about Ruby Object

Tags: ruby, object

I need information help about Object in ruby. In console I  see many puts "Module1". Why is this happening? Why am I seeing  so much "Module1". I try to use this code:

```
   class Object
      def method_missing(*args)

        puts 'Module1'
        super
      end
    end
```

Comment: You could replace `puts 'Module1'` with a more informative output, for example printing [`Kernel#caller`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) to see which class or method invokes `method_missing` (probably IRB).

Comment: _Sidenote:_ redefining `Object#method_missing`, specifically with a wrong signature, is a very bad idea.

Comment: Also : If `Object` doesn't have the defined method, `super` probably won't help much. You see so many 'Module1' because you're using IRB or PRY, and those aren't exactly Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

This has a lot to do with how ruby looks up methods. It traverses the ancestors tree twice. The first time looking for the method name, the second looking for `method_missing`.

Most objects inherit from `Object` so it's not unusual to see the `method_missing` of `Object` being invoked.

There are a lot of resources explaining this in more detail if you're interested. [This is a good one](https://gist.github.com/damien-roche/351bf4e7991449714533).